# How to select a single row from an sql table with multiple rows having same value in a column

Tags: sql

I have an sql table which current looks like this:

```
id |   Name   | Age|   City
______________________________
1  |   Mike   | 26 | New York
2  |   Nick   | 32 | London
3  |   Anne   | 22 | New York
4  |   Andy   | 24 | Lagos
5  |   Nickie | 27 | Paris
6  |   Sam    | 26 | London
```

I need to query the table to return something like:

```
id |   Name   | Age|   City
______________________________
1  |   Mike   | 26 | New York
2  |   Nick   | 32 | London
3  |   Andy   | 24 | Lagos
4  |   Nickie | 27 | Paris
```

so that all rows with same value for a particular column (city in this example) gets returned just once (only 1 of multiple rows with same column values gets returned). If i add a timestamp column, then i want only the latest row displayed. How do i write this sql

Comment: Use `LIMIT <number to limit to>`.  You could `ORDER BY` your timestamp column `DESC` and then limit to 1 to get the very latest.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL *flavor*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write required query like below if you have a column date_edited with type TIMESTAMP .

```
SET @@sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
SELECT Name, Age, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT City ORDER BY date_edited DESC) AS city 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY date_edited DESC
```

Comment: thanks @ vjy. I keep getting an error though. On phpMyAdmin console i get this error _#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'example.test.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by_

Comment: WHat data type you used for City column ?

Comment: You have to enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option

Comment: @banky I edited the answer , so it will work , try now

Comment: thanks. same error after implementing your edited answer. My city column is of varchar data type

Comment: I appreciate your assistance @vjy. After disabling the only_full_group_by through the WAMP icon, the sql statement worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150363/discussion-between-vjy-tiwari-and-banky).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, Age, City, MAX(TIME_STAMP_COLUMN) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY City;
```

This query will select all your rows, group them by your `City` column to remove duplicates, then return the row for each grouped city that has the greatest, or most recent, time stamp associated with it.

Comment: Nice catch, I looked at a wrong past example, but fixed it now

Comment: This is still invalid SQL because the `group by` is invalid. You need to include `name` and `age` as well

Comment: Thanks @yanman1234 . problem is i keep getting this error when i try it on myPhpAdmin console "#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'example.test.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by". Could it be a set-up issue with my phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you would use the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by city order by city) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You would use `order by timestamp desc` if you wanted the latest column.

Answer (score 1):

Disable only_full_group_by if you are on WAMP by following this sequence:
Left click on WAMP Icon, MySQL, MySQL settings, SQL mode, User mode. then restart your WAMP services. Then try your SQL after services restarted